# Extracting useful features from a PyTorch - efficient net-3b model

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I have a PyTorch CNN based on EfficientNet PyTorch (efficientnet-3b) that does a very good job at the binary classification (99% plus) of fairly complex chest x-rays. I want to extract features and use them in a related model. [EfficientNet PyTorch](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch#example-feature-extraction) has a very handy method `model.extract_features` with the given example

```py
features = model.extract_features(img)
print(features.shape) # torch.Size([1, 1280, 7, 7])
```

It works well and I get those results as advertised but I need the features more in the shape of [1, 516] or something similar. I need enough features to be fairly discriminatory but with not too many to be unwieldy.
I am familiar with the technique of adding a layer, or series of layers, ending with a fully connected layer with the outputs of the size that I need.

If that is what I need to do here can someone please lead me through the process, architecture etc. Also, it would be great if the solution leveraged the method mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest architecture would be ending you feature extractor with linear projection:

```
class MyExtractor:
    def __init__(self, extractor, features = 512):
        self.extractor = extractor
        self.projection = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Flatten(), torch.nn.LazyLinear(out_features))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.projection(self.extractor(x))
```

You can instantiate it like so:

```
m = MyExtractor(model, 512)
```

This will work with output features of any size.

You could also give larger `features` but L1 regularize the last layer to only get the most important features